# Password protect an alias virtual directory

Tags: apache, htaccess, authentication, cpanel, htpasswd

I have a main domain being hosted through CPanel. I also have a sub-domain that I would like to appear as a path under the main domain instead of as a sub-domain. So I have:

```
http://example.com/ pointing to the main hosted file.
http://example.com/mydir pointing to the subdomain files.
```

This is achieved by a *httpd.conf* include from the main domain section to set an alias:

```
alias /mydir /path/to/subdomain/files/
```

Now, that works fine so far.

The problem is that if a *.htaccess* file under `/path/to/the/subdomain/files/` contains an error, the alias is completely skipped, and `/mydir` goes instead to the main host files. That is kind of surprising to me - I would expect an error to return an error instead.

Now the killer: if I try to password protect `/path/to/subdomain/files/`, then trying to access `http://example.com/mydir` will again attempt to deliver from under the main hosted files and not from `/path/to/subdomain/files/`.

I am not seeing any errors reported on the *.htaccess* file in the apache error log, so I am assuming the *.htaccess* is valid:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/valid/readable/.htpasswd
AuthName "Secure Access"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

This kind of behavior does not seem right to me. Is there something obvious that could be causing it? Or is this just the way it works? Perhaps using an alias is the wrong way to go?

Comment: The reason for keeping the files in /mydir in a separate area (in a CPanel subdmain for convenince) is for organisation of the scripts. The reason for using an alias folder under the one domain is so they can share a certificate.

Comment: If I comment out `Require valid-user` from my .htaccess, then I see the files from /path/to/subdomain/files and if I uncomment `Require valid-user` then I see the main domain files (a Drupal CMS). How can requiring a valid user cause apache to deliver files from completely different directories?

Comment: Could I be missing an authentication module in httpd.conf? None seem to be set.

Comment: `alias /mydir /path/to/subdomain/files/` try making it `alias /mydir/ /path/to/subdomain/files/` with a trailing slash after the alias.

Comment: I've tried that, with no change. With `Require valid-user` set I see one directory (the wrong directory) and if I comment it out I see the right directory. In either case there is no user/password prompt and nothing in the apache error log.

Comment: Whats in your httpd.conf? There should be a few mod_auth named modules, usually uncommented by default... What happens when you try to access a password protected non aliased folder? Also instead of alias, you could use a symlink (or junction in windows) to alias the folder at the operating system level

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to use *.htaccess* for authentication?

I know you can simulate this in PHP with `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` ([documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php)). This would only work for PHP, but other languages probably support this kind of thing.